# Copy character using pointers with post-increment

Tags: c, pointers, post-increment

Recently I've been learning C and pointers.

In the book Programming in C by Stephen G. Kochan, I've met an example which I have difficulties of fully understand it.

To copy string `from` to string `to` using pointers, the example indicates:

```
void copyString (char *to, char *from) {
    while ( *from ) 
         *to++ = *from++;

    *to = '\0'; 
}
```

In my understanding, `*from++` is a post-increment of `*from`; thus the value of `*to++` should be `*from` only.

For instance, if

```
`*from` is in the position 1.

`*from++` is in position 2

`*to++` in position 2,
```

But: `*from++ = *to++` should return values of `*from` as `*to` position 1, not 2.

The compiler said it's position 2, the book also said it's position 2.

I'm a little bit confused here. Do you have any feasible explanation for this case?

Comment: It's equivalent to: `*to = *from; to++; from++;` - horrible, isn't it?

Comment: The K&R method is even shorter: `while (*to++ = *from++) {;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the postfix `++` unary operator, the increment is sequenced after the computation of the value of the operand. So the expression is equivalent to:

```
*to = *from;
to++ ;
from++ ;
```

In your example: `*to++ = *from++;`, the values of `*to` and `*from` are obtained and then the value of  `*from` is assigned to `*to`, then both pointers are incremented.

Answer (score 1):

`*to++ = *from++;` both `to` and `from` have post increment.

You can read like,

1. copy the contains of `*from` to `*to`
2. increment `to` and `from`.

The postfix operators are evaluated and the operation of increment (decrement) is performed once the evaluation of assignment operator `=` has finished. So, first the values are copied, then both the pointers are incremented.

Comment: Thank you.
I read sth like: 
1. increment of `*from`
2. pass value from `*to` to `*from1`
3. increment of `*to`

Comment: @ctn no, that's not the order. both the pointers will be incremented at the same time.

Comment: "*The postfix operators are evaluated once the assignment operator = has finished evaluation.*" This is not correct. The result of evaluating a postifx operator is the operand. Incrementing the operand is a side  effect of the evaluation and is sequenced after the computation done to and with the operand. See C11 Standard 6.5.2.4/2 and also *2501*'s answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27460162/694576

Comment: @alk my bad. poor choice of words. is it correct now?

Answer (score 0):

As a supplyment to previous answer.

In C, suffix increment `++` has higher precedence than dereference operator `*`, which means *ptr++ is equivalent to *(ptr++). Check [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for more info about operator precedence of C.

Comment: Which "*previous anwser*", please?

Comment: @alk. All previous answer explain what `*from++` do in a plain way. I am trying to explain it in a much abstract way(I mean operator precedence).